# replacement has x rows, data has y - paste() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to group by the following sample values,

latitude | longitude | TotalGreenhouseGases | Amount | Branch    |End Date
-37.80144|  144.95402|            42965.9868|32549.99|Arts and Culture| 07/31/2013 12:00:00 AM
-37.80144|  144.95402|            43246.6716|32762.63|Arts and Culture| 08/30/2013 12:00:00 AM
-37.80144|  144.95402|            21374.1264|16192.52|Arts and Culture| 09/31/2013 12:00:00 AM

```
mapdata <- aggregate(cbind(TotalGreenhouseGases,Amount) ~ latitude+longitude,data = dt2,FUN=function(dt2) c(mn =sum(dt2), n=length(dt2) ) )
```

163 obs. and 4 Variables are created as a result, now to plot it in a map using plot.ly i am trying to add a text for hovering,

```
mapdata$hover <- paste( mapdata$TotalGreenhouseGases, "CO2 Emission ",'<br>', "Resource Consumption ", mapdata$Amount)
```

but this results in the following error,

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "hover", value = c("264.06428571 CO2 Emission  <br> Resource Consumption  200",  : 
replacement has 326 rows, data has 163
```

can anyone let me know where I am going wrong or if it has been solved before can you please provide a link for that.

Comment: Could you please provide the output of 'str(mapdata)'?

Comment: I get the following 
'data.frame': 163 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ latitude            : num  -37.8 -37.8 -37.8 -37.8 -37.8 ...
 $ longitude           : num  145 145 145 145 145 ...
 $ TotalGreenhouseGases: num [1:163, 1:2] 264 1616 30480 0 3186 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "mn" "n"
 $ Amount              : num [1:163, 1:2] 200 1223 23085 4659 2410 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "mn" "n"

Comment: As far as I can see both the TotalGreenH... And the Amount column has dimension 2, therefore your output of the paste call is 2 * 163 . Did you try to assign the paste output to a new variable and check the length of it?

Comment: @FlorianSchunke : yes I tried using different variables, still I get the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the the problem is that the way you created `mapdata` you end up with a list of length of 2 for both `TotalGreenhouseGases` and `Amount`.

```
> str(mapdata)
'data.frame':  1 obs. of  5 variables:
  $ latitude            : num -37.8
$ longitude           : num 145
$ TotalGreenhouseGases: num [1, 1:2] 107587 3
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : NULL
.. ..$ : chr  "mn" "n"
$ Amount              : num [1, 1:2] 81505 3
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : NULL
.. ..$ : chr  "mn" "n"
```

So if you want to use the sum of these values in your `paste` function then you will need to use [1] indexing, if you need to use the sample size `n` then use [2]. For example:

```
mapdata$hover <- paste( mapdata$TotalGreenhouseGases[1], 
                        "CO2 Emission ",'<br>', "Resource Consumption ", 
                        mapdata$Amount[1])
```

will give you

```
[1] "107586.7848 CO2 Emission  <br> Resource Consumption  81505.14"
```

Comment: See 3rd comment under the question ;)

Comment: yup, I just saw it after I posted the answer...  you were faster!